# CSS: relatively positioned element with percentage top

Tags: css

I found a few questions about this, but not really a single answer that would satisfy me. I'm assuming it's not possible, but at the very least I'd like to know the logic behind it and why it's not possible.

What I want to achieve:
Two elements, parent and child, both with relative positioning. I'd like to apply `top: -50%` on the child, but it's not working as expected.

Basically I need the `.child` element to move towards the top by half of its own height.

html:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">some content <br> on two lines</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.child {
  position: relative;
  top: -50%;
}
```

Right now, I would expect the `.child` element's "vertical center" to be in line with the `.parent` element's top. I hope that makes sense.

I know that if I set absolute height on the parent, it will work. But thn I wouldn't need percentages, right?

As I said, I don't expect this to be possible, but it would be majorly helpful if someone explained to me why.

Thanks

Comment: By half of it's own height? use transform: translateY(-50%);

Comment: The reference points for percentages in CSS is the parent. It does not refer to the size of the current element. If the child element is the same size as the parent, it will work fine. See [this](http://jsbin.com/viqifohahi/edit?html,css,js,output) for an example. Using transforms, like @user3528269 said will achieve your goal. [These browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) support it.

Comment: `top: -50%` uses the parent div's width in calculating percentage. Use what's suggested in the above comment.

Comment: user3528269: I'm looking for a solution compatible IE9, which, if i remember correctly, this isn't. If i'm wrong, please correct me :).

user4040648: sadly, it will not work fine. In your example you used an absolute height for the parent, which, as i said in the original question, is not the solution i'm looking for.

@akinuri the top property is not based on parent element's width, but on it's height.

Anyway thank you for your responses guys, but i'd still like to know, why is this behaving as it is, since it seems to be working as intended, which i dont understand.

Comment: Nobody can answer this?

Comment: Is there really noone with enough knowledge to answer this? What is this site for than? This is my 3rd question here on stackoverflow and i didn't receive a proper answer for any of them :/

Comment: this is just great.. a asked a year ago.. still no answer :D